# Equating trigonometric identities: $\sqrt3\cos x - \sin x=0$

Tags: trigonometry, alternative-proof

So I was given the equation below and was told to solve for x.

$$\sqrt3\cos(x) - \sin(x) = 0,x \in [-\pi, \pi] $$

Naturally I rearranged the equation to be:

$$\sqrt3\cos(x) = \sin(x)$$

Once I had it in this form, it was obvious to me that this equation would be true for when $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(x) = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ or the negative version of each of these. I then proceeded to solve the question.

However, I feel that this step is "not good enough" in terms of a mathematical solution. Is there a better way that we can find $x$ without having to just mentally guess what it is going to be? Obviously it is fairly easy to do in this case, but I don't want to be blindsided by a harder question of the same type in the future.

Any more formal proofs/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\implies\sqrt3=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}=?$$

$$\tan x=\tan\dfrac\pi3\implies x=n\pi+\dfrac\pi3$$ where $n$ is any integer.

Choose $n$ such that $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize it would be that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We generally solve as follows: $$\sqrt {3}\cos x =\sin x $$ $$\tan x =\sqrt {3} =\tan 60^\circ $$ The general solution for this equation is $x =n\pi +\frac {\pi}{3}, n\in \mathbb Z $. Substituting for the values of $n $, we get solutions in the required range.

---

If you want to learn more, see [here](https://mathspace.co/learn/world-of-maths/trig-functions-rad/general-solutions-to-trig-equations-33972/general-solutions-1736/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt {3} cosx - sinx = 0$$
Dividing both sides by $2$.
$$\frac {\sqrt {3}}{2} cosx - \frac {1}{2} sinx = 0$$
$$sin 60°.cos x- cos 60°.sinx=0$$
$$sin(60-x)°=0$$
$$x=60°,120°$$.

.............